# How to read file with delimiters using fscanf?

Tags: c, file, scanf, delimiter

I am trying to read a file and store the information to the following buffers

```
    char bookCode[MAX];
    char title [MAX];
    char author [MAX];
    char year [MAX];
    float selfCost;
    float selfPrice;
```

My file data looks like this

```
1738|Jane Eyre|Charlotte Bronte|1997|2.5|4.09
2743|The Kite Runner|Khaled Hosseini|2018|6.32|8.9
6472|Memoirs of a Geisha|Arthur Golden|2011|4.21|6.61
7263|The Divine Comedy|Dante|2009|5.59|7.98
3547|Outlander|Diana Gabaldon|1996|10.99|12.07
```

Currently, I have tried the following

```
while (fscanf(fi, "%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%f|%f",bookCode,title,author,year,&selfCost,&selfPrice)==6)
```

But it only reads one line and then stops. Any suggestions?

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define INPUT "HW2_file1.txt"
#define MAX 1000 

int main(void)
{

    FILE *fi = fopen(INPUT, "r");
    if (fi!=NULL)
    {
        printf ("Input file is opened sucesfully\n");
    }
    else
    {
        perror ("Error opening the file: \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ReadingData(fi);

    fclose(fi);
    return 0;
}
void ReadingData (FILE *fi)
{
    int i=0;
    char bookCode[MAX];
    char title [MAX];
    char author [MAX];
    char year [MAX];
    float selfCost;
    float selfPrice;
    while (fscanf(fi, " %[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%f|%f",bookCode,title,author,year,&selfCost,&selfPrice)==6)
    {

        printf ("%s %s %s %s %.2f %.2f\n",bookCode,title,author,year,selfCost,selfPrice);
        i++;
        printf ("%d\n",i);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 #define MAX 30

Comment: Having put a C wrapper around that, cannot reproduce. Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem. Note that each `bookCode` will start with a newline, except the first one. You can filter that out by adding a space before the first `%` as in `fscanf(fi, " %[^|]...`

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry, I don't understand what else is needed because I posted everything needed for reproducing (except the part with opening the file)

Comment: A MRE which shows the problem can be copy/pasted, compiled and run, so that I can experience the same fault. You have not posted the part which shows the fault. As commented, I tried using your posted code, but it did not "stop after the first line". So I then had to make a guess that it might be something to do with the stray newlines being present.

Comment: One Side-Question: Wouldn´t you rather store each line element in a separate array dimension instead of all elements just in one one-dimensional array, f.e. if you want to gather just the information of one only element, like `Jane Eyre`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I added the screenshot, hope it's enough. Did it run fine when you have tested it?

Comment: I am sorry: "You have not posted the part which shows the fault" means the ***code***. The *complete* code.  I have already said *twice* that the code you posted runs. We need the code that produces the screen shot (which is using different data from what you posted).

Comment: @WeatherVane Ahh, got it now and added the code as well

Comment: This still isn't complete.  There are no includes, no definition of `data`, no definition of `INPUT`, etc.  We need to be able to copy-and-paste your code *as-is* and be able to compile and run it.

Comment: Sorry, having removed the syntax errors, irrelevant function argument `books` and added some missing parts it works correctly (apart from the stray newlines already mentioned).

Comment: Did you run the code you posted against the file with the contents you posted?  Because when I do I see all 5 rows printed.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you, at least now I know that the problem isn't in the fscanf function that I thought before

Comment: Well it is: you must filter the newline anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've tried both ways and it still works. Does it really make any difference?

Comment: If you really want a newline at the start of each bookcode, just ignore me. Try changing each of the `%s` in `printf` to `[%s]` and you will see what I mean. the [brackets] will show you where the unwanted newlines are. Without that, you are probably overlooking the difference: the output is double-spaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works (as long as I reorder the definitions to define `ReadingData` before calling it, add the necessary `#include` and `#define MAX`, and simplify it to get rid of the unused `data` type; I also squished the variable declarations down to try and make the TIO link fit in a comment, but that ended up being futile):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 256

void ReadingData (FILE *fi)
{
    int i=0;
    char bookCode[MAX], title[MAX], author[MAX], year[MAX];
    float selfCost, selfPrice;
    while (fscanf(fi, " %[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%f|%f",bookCode,title,author,year,&selfCost,&selfPrice)==6)
    {

        printf ("%s %s %s %s %.2f %.2f\n",bookCode,title,author,year,selfCost,selfPrice);
        i++;
        printf ("%d\n",i);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    ReadingData(stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

[Click this *Try it online!* link](https://tio.run/##fZJRb9MwEMff/SlOnTalLESJ2ySNSpFGOwaMCTTxgDSG5MX2ciK1keMMVXM/e3GSteNhwrLOZ53vfmf/Xb6@L8vd7ghVWbdcwJvGctRR9ZaQIy4kKgFXZ9@BphkhDxo5XAvGUd2vmGUQvP/4@RxeSRyTRwJ@oLKAi3jeb8qKGbjT@tdSc3Hjq9yGYNHWe5@1ttLmabMRbHCHXFlrZqERtVzqxoa999VgKYbwnwprAYFsSqZkIDGEERzf/HS37gUr/RyF@0bCvoVwgIcdNjw5cE4OnPFikY171iPpl278Nv6CEoLRcQPPM6KyNz/UfykHyDNjfqiMp6fzFzC8q4lP57ZkS0j3wmuGKujE2D/7P5oEnX7KZ/QBI2xrFHhBtrtdkk9m7hPzip5vjHBLL0@trRXwzmhlhUuKInc0St00igtC8@nEfasEXKI/ct0qJYy7rFgtOHzQTSNQoaNxMnNZNKFuFhUkm@bUXYm1RtOAlsDgQmBTMXdmbNUauNA1F6pLSjyDJj4zS0hOswG0wofuuy31WvCNW7GuJxrHhUujtHB5VMzIJJ3m7ktra6a4b2eFTHkIu2M116q7QOaSOCoKl9Aozv8C) and it will run, just fine, with the input you provided. So either your input is wrong, you've omitted code, or you've got some other problem that the lack of a minimal, reproducible example is concealing.